# Error executing access token command "/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config-helper --format=json

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

I'm trying to follow this step by step to upload the airflow in Kubernetes (https://github.com/EamonKeane/airflow-GKE-k8sExecutor-helm) but in this part of the execution I have problems as follows:

Researching on the topic did not find anything that solved so far my problem, does anyone have any suggestions of what to do?

```
SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://$AIRFLOW_DB_USER:$AIRFLOW_DB_USER_PASSWORD@$KUBERNETES_POSTGRES_CLOUDSQLPROXY_SERVICE:$KUBERNETES_POSTGRES_CLOUDSQLPROXY_PORT/$AIRFLOW_DB_NAME

echo $SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN > /secrets/airflow/sql_alchemy_conn
# Create the fernet key which is needed to decrypt database the database
FERNET_KEY=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null | openssl base64)
echo $FERNET_KEY > /secrets/airflow/fernet-key

kubectl create secret generic airflow \
    --from-file=fernet-key=/secrets/airflow/fernet-key \
    --from-file=sql_alchemy_conn=/secrets/airflow/sql_alchemy_conn
```

> Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command
>   "/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper
>   --format=json": err=exit status 1 output= stderr=ERROR: gcloud crashed (BadStatusLine): '' If you would like to report this issue, please run
>   the following command:   gcloud feedback To check gcloud for common
>   problems, please run the following command:   gcloud info
>   --run-diagnostics

Comment: Which of the copy-pasted steps invokes `gcloud`, as I don't see anything in your posting with `config-helper --format=json` and we don't have the time or energy to play "guess where this command lives"

Comment: Please provide more details how to recreate your issue. 
As per your tutorial "The only requirement for the following installation is to have docker-compose, google cloud sdk" So please verify your env variables as described in the link. 
You can also use other more up to date [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new cloud shell tab to connect the cluster:

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials testcluster1 --zone = your_zone`

Answer (score 15):

Example:

get the name and location of your cluster

```
gcloud container clusters list
```

then

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials demo --region=us-west1-a
```